# How to store an integer value in isolated storage in wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I want store an integer value in isolated storage in wp7 so that when i close and open the app again, the value should be retained. How can I obtained this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's to store a single integer value, the easiest way is to use [`IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.applicationsettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
// Store the value
IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Whatever"] = yourValue;

// Retrieve it
yourValue = (int)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Whatever"];
```